Exclude attachments from E-Mail Signature - save the rest to OneDrive
I have created a flow in Power Automate that creates a flagged email as a Planner task and attaches the email attachments to the task by storing them on OneDrive. However, many emails contain images in the footer or signature, which is why I am trying to exclude these images. At the same time, I would like to keep images inserted by the sender.
Currently, I filter out the footer images using file names (image001.png...), but this does not work well for different signatures and if there are pictures added to the body the names of the pictures in the signature are incremented. Excluding the file type in general is also not an option.
What can I do to distinguish the images inserted by the signature from other images in the attachments or the body?

Is there a noticeable difference between the file sizes of in-line text images and signature images?

While the social media icons are quite smal some of the company logos might be as big as the images in the mail body...
